# NSDictionary: URL-Encoding

Tags: objective-c, nsdictionary, url-encoding

Can anyone please review the following method and tell me if it is necessary to release the enumerator for the dictionary keys after using it?
I'm new to objective c and not always sure, when to release variables returned from the SDK methods. I suppose the keyEnumerator method returns an autoreleased instance so I don't have to care about it when I'm finished with it. Right?

Hmm.. maybe anything else wrong in this method? ;)

```
#import "NSDictionaryURLEncoding.h"
#import <Foundation/NSURL.h>

@implementation NSDictionary(URLEncoding)

-(NSString *)urlEncoded
{
   NSEnumerator *keyEnum = [self keyEnumerator];
   NSString *currKey;
   NSString *currObject;
   NSMutableString *result = [NSMutableString stringWithCapacity: 64];

   while ((currKey = [keyEnum nextObject]) != nil)
   {
      if ([result length] > 0)
      {
         [result appendString: @"&"];
      }
      currObject = [[self objectForKey: currKey] stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
      currKey = [currKey stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

      [result appendString: [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@=%@", currKey, currObject]];
   }
   return result;
}

@end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You **must never** `release` objects for which you did not call the `alloc` method if you also didn't `retain` them. See the [Memory Management Programming Guide for Cocoa](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/).

Also, if you're programming for the iPhone OS or if you are targetting Mac OS X 10.5 or later, I suggest you use the `for(... in ...)` language construct to enumerate through your dictionary. It's much faster than using enumerators.

```
for(NSString* currKey in self)
{
    NSString* currObject = [self objectForKey:currKey];
    // the rest of your loop code
}
```

You should read the [Fast Enumeration](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/DOCUMENTATION/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Articles/ocFastEnumeration.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001163-CH18-SW1) section of the Objective-C Programming Language Reference.

I also suggest, as a friendly advice, that you don't extend NSDictionary or create a category on it unless you really, really need it.

Comment: Thank you.

Yes, there are many specs I still have to read, I know. Unfortunately the day only has 24 hours. I'm just through the "Beginning iPhone 3 Development" book and the Stanford podcasts and now in the "learning by doing" phase.

I moved the method to a class where it's needed. ;)

Lessons learned today:

- If you did not allocate or retain things, don't care about releasing them
- Never extends SDK classes, when there is another solution